# Access ViewModel inside Testcase using Hilt

Tags: unit-testing, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Can anyone suggest me that how can I access ViewModel inside Test case using Hilt?

ViewModel class:

```
@HiltViewModel
class BaseViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: BaseRepository) : ViewModel()
```

AppModule for Hilt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideBaseApi(
        remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource
    ): BaseApi {
        return remoteDataSource.buildApi(BaseApi::class.java)
    }
```

Test case file

```
@SmallTest
@HiltAndroidTest
class BaseViewModelTest  {

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Inject
    lateinit var baseRepository: BaseRepository


    @BindValue
    @JvmField
    var viewModel = mockk<BaseViewModel>(relaxed = true)


    @Before
    fun init(){
        hiltRule.inject()
    }
```

It is not giving any access to mutable data of ViewModel class.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking `ViewModel` will not work when you run test which launches Activity or Fragment.

As in your case launched `MainActivity` will have its own `ViewModelStore` and hence will have a different `BaseViewModel`.

You can access `ViewModel` from the activity as below

```kotlin
private lateinit var viewModel: BaseViewModel

@Before
fun init() {
    activityRule.scenario.onActivity {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(it)[BaseViewModel::class.java]
    }
}
```

For fragment use,

```kotlin
private lateinit var viewModel: BaseViewModel

@Before
fun init() {
    launchFragmentInHiltContainer<MainFragment>().onFragment {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(it)[BaseViewModel::class.java]
    }
}
```